# how can i uniquely add options to select using jquery

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a bunch of unique options in a `<select>`. I need to add a new option only if it is unique and not present in the existing options.

How can I find if a given `option` already exists in a given `select` using jquery?

For example:

```
<select id="combobox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Pears">Pears</option>
</select>
```

- New valid option: Pear
- New invalid option: Apple

Comment: Extension to my question: Is there a utility that can give me an intersection of these two sets ? (I know I can write it easily, but if something already exists, I'd rather reuse it). For e.g. givenOptions and newOptions. I'd like to add the intersection of these two to givenOptions.

Comment: [Watch my updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10798112/601179) to your case-insensitive request.

Comment: What do you mean by 'intersection of the two options'?

Comment: @DavidThomas Existing options (givenOptions in this case: Apple, Banana, Pears). newOptions is like an array (which I get through an ajax call, for example [apple, plums]). I'd like to get the intersection of `givenOptions` and `newOptions` to find unique elements in the two set and add those to `givenOptions`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (!$("#combobox option[value='Apple']").length)
    // Add it
```

Making it reusable can be:

```
if (!$("#combobox option[value='" + value + "']").length)
    // Add it
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FVry9/1)

**case insensitive:**

```
var isExist = !$('#combobox option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('value').toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase();
}).length;​
```

**Full code:**(of the demo)

```
$('#txt').change(function() {
    var value = this.value;

    var isExist = !!$('#combobox option').filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr('value').toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase();
    }).length;

    if (!isExist) {
        console.log(this.value + ' is a new value!');
        $('<option>').val(this.value).text(this.value).appendTo($('#combobox'));
    }
});​
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FVry9/2/)

Comment: How can I make this case-insensitive ?

Comment: Awesome! can you please explain what is the `!!` operator in jquery ? I couldn't understand this part: `!!$('#combobox option').filter(...`

Comment: Thanks gdoron! That was helpful. Are you aware of  a a utility that can give me an intersection of these two `options` ? (I know I can write it easily, but if something already exists, I'd rather reuse it). For e.g. givenOptions from the current set of options and newOptions received as a json array. I'd like to add the intersection of these two to givenOptions. my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796413/how-to-use-jquery-autocomplete-combobox-with-ajax-json-data

Comment: @brainydexter. There is no built in way for it. You'll need to write it yourself. It's not that hard, proximity 3-5 lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you want to search by `value` rather than by the text content. In your example, they're always the same, but possibly they won't always be...

```
var toAdd = 'Apricot',
    combobox = $('#combobox');

if (!combobox.find('option[value="' + toAdd + '"]').length) {
    combobox.append('<option value="' + toAdd + '">' + toAdd + '</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the new option-text is present in the `newOption` variable:

```
$('button').click(
    function() {
        var newOption = $('#newOptionInput').val(),
            opts = [];
        $('#combobox option').each(
            function() {
                opts.push($(this).text());
            });

        if ($.inArray(newOption, opts) == -1) {
            $('<option />')
                .val(newOption)
                .text(newOption)
                .appendTo('#combobox');
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MMRZA/).

**Edited** to correct the above code (I forgot that `$.inArray()` returns `-1`, not `false` when a value isn't found), and use a more appropriate selector.

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`$.inArray()`/`jQuery.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).
- [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Will this not search in all the "option" on the given page ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#combobox').find('option[value="Pear"]').length) {
  // there's pear
} else {
  // nope, no pear
}
```