# How to make autocomplete search field in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am making an autocomplete search field in CodeIgniter, but it's not working properly. There is limit of 10 but every time when I enter the character the list became long and long like showing in the images:

[image]

[image: images of autocomplete search field]

here is my controller:

```
    function search_fields(){

    $country_id = $this->input->get('term');
    $data['var']= $this->Travel->search_field($country_id); 
    echo json_encode($data['var']);

}
```

here is my model:

```
 function search_field($country_id){
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select("destination");
    $this->db->from('travels_detail');
    $this->db->like('destination', $country_id);
     $this->db->group_by('travels_detail.destination');
     $this->db->limit(10);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

and here is my view:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#text').keyup( function() {
        var min_length = 0; 
    var keyword = $('#text').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/new/index.php/travels/search_fields',
            type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'json',
            data: { term: $("#text").val()},
            success:function(data){
                $.each(data, function() {
  $.each(this, function(k, v) {
      $("#demo").append("<li>" + v + "</li>");
  });
});
     }
        });
    } else {
        $('#demo').hide();
    }
});
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
 <input type="text" name="text" id="text" autocomplete="off" > 
</form>
<ul id="demo"> </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Also I want that user can select the value of input field from drop down. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Unset the `demo` div each time when ajax is called

Comment: Please refer this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804525/jquery-autocomplete-in-codeigniter-retrieving-values-but-not-displaying-them

Answer (score 2):

You forgot clean the html from #demo.When the success property occurs in Ajax Remove All Contents from #demo :

```
success:function(data){
   $("#demo").html('');
    $.each(data, function() {
      $.each(this, function(k, v) {
          $("#demo").append("<li>" + v + "</li>");
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: yes list is not expanding now, but it shows the same result not changing with characters

Answer (score 0):

In Model return `result_array` :

```
return $query->result_array();
```

In Controller :

```
$search_data = $this->Travel->search_field($term); 
echo json_encode($search_data);
```

Now, you can use jquery [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for retrieving values from database.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        $( "#text" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/new/index.php/travels/search_fields",
                data: { term: $("#text").val()},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    var resp = $.map(data,function(obj){
                        return obj.destination;
                   }); 
                   response(resp);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
        });
    });
});
</script>
```